# D3 choropleth + overpass api >> csv URL call = invalid characters in csv header?

Tags: csv, d3.js, choropleth, overpass-api

Experimenting a bit here with using an overpass api URL call >> csv for direct d3 charting. As longitude and latitude are special column declarations for overpass (called with an initial ::), they result in a CSV column header with an '@' symbol: @lon & @lat respectively.

If I change d.lon & d.lat to d.@lon & d.@lat in a function, I get an invalid character error.

Is there a way to get around this, eg telling overpass to use different header names without the @, parsing the @ columns to an @-free string before using them in the function, or somehow escaping the @ symbols?

Many thanks

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
width = +svg.attr("width"),
height = +svg.attr("height");

d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "map.geojson")  
  .defer(d3.csv, "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[bbox:37.8885,-122.2966,37.8906,-122.2945][out:csv(::lat,::lon,::id,wheelchair)];(node[entrance];);out;>;out skel qt;")  
  .await(ready);

svg
  .selectAll("myCircles")
  .data(data.sort(function(a,b) { return +b.n - +a.n }).filter(function(d,i){ return < 10 }))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d){ return projection(+d.@lon, +d.@lat)[0] })
  .attr("cy", function(d){ return projection(+d.@lon, +d.@lat)[1] })
  .attr("r", 5)
```

Comment: A JS attribute cannot begin with a `@` character

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky That clears that up. Thank you. I've worked out a middleman method - google apps scripting the overpass api call (without header) into a gsheet with custom header, and then getting the csv from the google sheet instead. Good enough for now.

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I came back to this question. I can make the overpass api call json instead of csv, e.g. with `http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%5Bbbox%3A37.8885,-122.2966,37.8906,-122.2945%5D%5Bout%3Ajson%5D;(node%5Bentrance%5D;);out;%3E;out%20skel%20qt;`, which doesn't have the @ symbol issue. I'm sure d3 can parse the json version, but I have not been able to get it to work in my code. Do you see a possible avenue?